# How to make the tbody vertically scrollable and autofill parent?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying really hard to get a table to fill up the rest of its parent element and make it scrollable at the same time, but I'm not having much luck. I've tried a bunch of different solutions from StackOverflow, and I've also tried doing things manually, but nothing seems to work. Here's a code example that shows what I'm trying to achieve. Ideally, the table would automatically fill the vertical space in all three of the cards and be scrollable too. Any ideas on how I could make this happen? I

https://jsfiddle.net/xsL1bjko/

```
html {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(0, 50, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.container div {
  width: 250px;
  
}
.ex-1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 100, 100);
  height: 100px;
 
}

.ex-2 {
  background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
  height: 150px;
}

.ex-3 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  height: 200px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add CSS properties:

```
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

to these selectors .ex-1 .ex-2 .ex-2

```
.ex-1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 100, 100);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.ex-2 {
  background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.ex-3 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

---

UPD according to the comments
You can use the *position: sticky* property for the table headers:

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(0, 50, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.container div {
  width: 250px;
  
}
.ex-1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 100, 100);
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.ex-2 {
  background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.ex-3 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
thead {
  position: sticky;
  inset-block-start: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <div class='ex-1'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Header 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='ex-2'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Header 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class='ex-3'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Header 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>James</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes ex-1/2/3 scrollable, not the tbody, it also changes the height of them, doesn't make the table fill in the content. thanks though

Comment: As far as I know the table itself or the tbody can't be scrolable. 
But there is another sollution with the sticky thead.
https://jsfiddle.net/Ravell/u968px1e/